# How to get records recursively with condition in Postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursive-query

I have two tables:

`locations`:

```
locationid   parentid
  1
  2              1
  3              1
  4              2
  5              4
  8              1
```

`approvelog`:

```
locationid  approved
   4          True
   8          True
```

I need to write a query which gives all sub-locations of a specific location, but if the locationid is approved then ignore it and its children, even if the children were not approved.

In simple words, when encountering a locationid that has `approved=True`, ignore it and all its children (meaning stop recursion for this branch).

For example:

- for `locationid=2` I want to get:

  ```
  2
  ```
- for `locationid=8` I want to get:

  ```
  Nothing
  ```
- for `locationid=1` I want to get:

  ```
  1,2,3
  ```

  4 is approved so ignore it and its children. 8  is approved so ignore it.

This is my code:

```
with recursive location_tree as (
   select  locationid, parentid
   from locations
   where locationid = 1 and not approved
   union all
   select child.locationid, child.parentid
   from locations child
   join location_tree parent on parent.locationid = child.parentid
   where child.active
)
select array_agg(locationid) 
from location_tree
```

This simply gives a list of locations.

Basically what I need is a "Stop Condition" for the recursion.
How do I change it to work?

Can someone help?

Comment: You can use order by  in 'with'

Comment: I don't see how order by will solve my problem? My problem is that I get all children from the recursion... I don't want to get all of them... I only want to get the relevant ones. Order by won't solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I used in PostgreSQL to get the parent and its non-approved children assuming the parent itself is also not approved:

```
WITH recursive location_tree AS (
  --PARENT
  SELECT
    p.locationid,
    p.parentid
  FROM
    locations p
  LEFT JOIN
    approvelog pa ON pa.locationid = p.locationid AND pa.approved = TRUE
  WHERE
    p.locationid = 1
    AND pa.locationid IS NULL --Exclude approved parent
  UNION ALL

  --CHILD
  SELECT 
    c.locationid,
    c.parentid
  FROM 
    locations c
  JOIN 
    location_tree p on p.locationid = c.parentid
  LEFT JOIN
    approvelog ca ON ca.locationid = c.locationid AND ca.approved = TRUE
  WHERE
    ca.locationid IS NULL --Exclude approved children
)
SELECT 
  array_agg(locationid) 
FROM 
  location_tree
```

SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/7084f/19

Answer (score 0):

I believe @vanlee1987's answer is a good one.  Alternatively, you can wrap this in a function and do actual recursion (not recursive SQL) within the function itself.  For example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION location_tree(location_id integer)
  RETURNS integer[] AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
  result integer[];
  r locations%rowtype;
BEGIN

  select array[l.locationid]
  into result
  from
    locations l
    left join approvelog a on
      l.locationid = a.locationid
  where
    l.locationid = location_id and
   (a.approved is null or a.approved = false);

  for r in
    select
      l.locationid, l.parentid
    from
      locations l
    where
      l.parentid = any (result)
  loop
    result := array_cat(result, location_tree(r.locationid));
  end loop;

  return result;
end
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

Implementation:

```
select location_tree(1);     // yields {1,2,3}
select location_tree(2);     // yields {2}
select location_tree(8);     // yields {}
```